# Rigging a double hinge

Tags: animation, transforms

So, I am trying to make one of those concealed door hinges.
I cannot make it work to save my life. I have tried several things but nothing really made it work the way it is supposed to work.

The arms are supposed to rotate on both connected cylinders and hide inside the housing, while the cylinders inside the housing are sliding further inside to make space for the arms.

I've added a few pictures and a video, I hope you understand what I'm trying to say and can help me out.

[image: That's the cylinder that's supposed to slide inside]

[image: rotating animation]

[image: Animation of how it is supposed to look like]

[image: Picture of what it is supposed to look like]

Comment: Can you add a specific reference of what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: Yes, I have added an animation and a picture I found on google. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those types of mechanisms I would suggest doing it with a simple rig. The end cylinders are driven by the most open hinge where rotation controls the position of both. And the position of the joints are handled on two bones with an IK constraint.
Here I leave you the [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KbLpFvT5i9RPj_kO7TGjZElNZgqV8MTM/view?usp=sharing) where you can see the constraints that I used.

In this link there is a video that shows how the mechanism works: [Video hinge mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emfzw.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I want to rig the same thing but I cannot open the project or the video. Can you please reupload it again? Thank You!

Comment: @FelixLeung in this case, I think it's reasonable for you to post your problem as a question in its own right. Leonardo has not followed the guideline asking for answers to be self-contained.